# How to automatically download all my pics from my website not using FTP?

Tags: hosting, download

On one free web-hosted place I build a site, well not actually a site, but just uploaded a folder with many sub folders inside containing many pictures. Now, I have discovered that this hosting is going to close soon and they gave their users one month t save all the materials. Of course, i can enter each folder manually and use "Save as" in my browser, but I wonder how I could do that automatically. Is there any such way? By the way it shouldn't be FTP - it doesn't work there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you don't have any kind of command line access to your web host, you could use `wget` to download the images from your site.

Something like `wget -r -A .jpg,.gif,.png` where `-r` mean recursive (i.e. descend into subdirectories) and `-A` means filter for ("accept") files ending with the comma-separated list of extensions.

Answer (score 3):

one word: [`wget`](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html)